# python get users from mysql and create them on linux

Tags: python, mysql, linux

Im am trying to add users in mysql then create them on my Linux system with a python script.

```
with dbcon:
    cur = dbcon.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
    result = cur.fetchall()       

    c = csv.writer(open("users.csv","wb"))
    c.writerow(result)

if dbcon:
    dbcon.close()
```

With this i just get an ugly csv file ....

Comment: "create them on Linux system?" - Explanation would help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all - your not adding users to mysql, you're reading them from it and just dumping it to a csv file.
What you want is to do a INSERT INTO .... query and then run a shell command to add a user (read the useradd command manual for details)